# BroadcastReceiver permission

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

In the android doc of BroadcastReceiver:

> **android:permission** The name of a permission that broadcasters must
>   have to send a message to the broadcast receiver. If this attribute is
>   not set, the permission set by the  element's permission
>   attribute applies to the broadcast receiver. If neither attribute is
>   set, the receiver is not protected by a permission.

**I have set a custom permission in application tag** and I also have a receiver that trying to receive **MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED** broadcast. And I get the following warning message when the system trying to broadcast my listener event.

```
Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent {
 act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
 dat=file:///mnt/sdcard } from com.android.providers.media (pid=767,
 uid=10029) requires com.xxx.permission due to receiver
 com.xxx.myreceiver
```

How can I get the broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have defined also `scheme` in `data` specification of an intent filter for your receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Better post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.